# Can't update eclipse getting errors

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a really old version of eclipse (Eclipse Java Oxygen) and I've been trying to update it.

I went to Help>Check for updates and got the error: `Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest/compositeContent.xml. Address family not supported by protocol family: connect`

I then tried to install anyway and got this error:

```
`An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=C__Users_billy_eclipse_java-oxygen_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.gradleware.tooling.client,0.19.4.v20171108133209
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.gradleware.tooling.model,0.19.4.v20171108133209
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.gradleware.tooling.utils,0.19.4.v20171108133209
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ant.launching,1.2.1.v20171108-0853
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.buildship.branding,2.2.1.v20180125-1441
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.buildship.core,2.2.1.v20180125-1441
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.buildship.stsmigration,2.2.1.v20180125-1441
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.buildship.ui,2.2.1.v20180125-1441
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.jobs,3.9.3.v20180115-1757
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt,0.14.102.v20180117-1153
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.eclemma.core,3.1.0.201804041601
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.eclemma.doc,3.1.0.201804041601
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.eclemma.ui,3.1.0.201804041601
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit,4.9.2.201712150930-r
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.core,4.9.2.201712150930-r
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.doc,4.9.2.201712150930-r
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.ui,4.9.2.201712150930-r
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.ui,4.9.2.201712150930-r
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.epp.logging.aeri.core,2.0.7.v20170906-1327
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.epp.logging.aeri.ide,2.0.7.v20170906-1327
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core,1.6.4.v20180214-1810
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core.win32,1.6.4.v20180214-1800
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.epp.mpc.help.ui,1.6.4.v20180214-1800
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.epp.mpc.ui,1.6.4.v20180214-1800
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.epp.package.common,4.7.3.20180405-1200
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.epp.package.java,4.7.3.20180405-1200
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64,1.1.551.v20171108-1834
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui,2.5.2.v20171013-1525
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator,1.2.1.v20180131-1435
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.help.base,4.2.153.v20180330-0640
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt,3.13.4.v20180330-0640
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core,3.5.100.v20180322-1206
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.apt.pluggable.core,1.2.50.v20180322-1206
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.apt.ui,3.5.50.v20180322-1206
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.apt,1.3.110.v20180329-0935
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.tool,1.2.101.v20180329-0935
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.core,3.13.102.v20180330-0919
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.core.manipulation,1.9.100.v20180321-0831
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui,3.8.100.v20180322-1256
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user,3.13.75.v20180329-0655
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.junit,3.10.75.v20180322-1731
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.junit.core,3.9.100.v20180321-0831
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.junit.runtime,3.4.651.v20171130-0906
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.junit5.runtime,1.0.1.v20171130-0906
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.launching,3.9.100.v20180323-1351
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.ui,3.13.100.v20180330-0726
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jetty.continuation,9.4.8.v20171121
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jetty.http,9.4.8.v20171121
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jetty.io,9.4.8.v20171121
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jetty.security,9.4.8.v20171121
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jetty.server,9.4.8.v20171121
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jetty.servlet,9.4.8.v20171121
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jetty.util,9.4.8.v20171121
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jface,3.13.2.v20171022-1656
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jface.text,3.12.2.v20180112-1341
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jgit,4.9.2.201712150930-r
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jgit.archive,4.9.2.201712150930-r
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.archetype.common,1.8.3.20180227-2135
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.core,1.8.3.20180227-2137
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui,1.8.3.20180227-2137
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.discovery,1.8.3.20180227-2137
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.editor,1.8.3.20180227-2137
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.editor.xml,1.8.3.20180227-2137
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.importer,1.8.3.20180227-2137
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.jdt,1.8.3.20180227-2137
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.ui,1.8.3.20180227-2137
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.launching,1.8.3.20180227-2137
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.lifecyclemapping.defaults,1.8.3.20180227-2137
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender,1.8.3.20180227-2137
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration,1.8.3.20180227-2137
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.maven.indexer,1.8.3.20180227-2135
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime,1.8.3.20180227-2135
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple,1.8.3.20180227-2135
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.model.edit,1.8.3.20180227-2137
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.profiles.core,1.8.3.20180227-2137
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.profiles.ui,1.8.3.20180227-2137
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.refactoring,1.8.3.20180227-2137
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.scm,1.8.3.20180227-2137
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext,3.0.19.20171117145831
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.ant,3.0.19.20171117145831
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.asciidoc,3.0.19.20171117145831
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.asciidoc.ui,3.0.19.201711172000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.confluence,3.0.19.20171117145831
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.confluence.ui,3.0.19.201711172000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.context.ui,3.0.19.201711172000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.help.ui,3.0.19.201711172000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.html,3.0.19.20171117145831
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.markdown,3.0.19.20171117145831
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.markdown.ui,3.0.19.201711172000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.mediawiki,3.0.19.20171117145831
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.mediawiki.ui,3.0.19.201711172000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.osgi,3.0.19.201711172000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.tasks.ui,3.0.19.201711172000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.textile,3.0.19.20171117145831
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.textile.ui,3.0.19.201711172000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.tracwiki,3.0.19.20171117145831
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.tracwiki.ui,3.0.19.201711172000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.twiki,3.0.19.20171117145831
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.twiki.ui,3.0.19.201711172000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.ui,3.0.19.201711172000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.osgi,3.12.100.v20180210-1608
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.platform,4.7.3.v20180330-0640
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.platform.doc.user,4.7.3.v20180328-1557
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.rcp,4.7.3.v20180330-0640
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.apidocs,2.5.2.v20180401-1226
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.apidocs.rcp,2.5.2.v20180401-1226
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.calls,2.5.2.v20180401-1226
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.calls.rcp,2.5.2.v20180401-1226
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.chain.rcp,2.5.2.v20180401-1226
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.completion.rcp,2.5.2.v20180401-1226
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.constructors,2.5.2.v20180401-1226
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.constructors.rcp,2.5.2.v20180401-1226
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.coordinates,2.5.2.v20180401-1226
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.coordinates.rcp,2.5.2.v20180401-1226
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.injection,2.5.2.v20180401-1226
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.jayes,2.5.2.v20180401-1226
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.jayes.io,2.5.2.v20180401-1226
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.jdt,2.5.2.v20180401-1226
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.models,2.5.2.v20180401-1226
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.models.rcp,2.5.2.v20180401-1226
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.mylyn.rcp,2.5.2.v20180401-1226
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.net,2.5.2.v20180401-1226
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.news,2.5.2.v20180401-1226
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.news.api,2.5.2.v20180401-1226
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.news.impl,2.5.2.v20180401-1226
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.news.rcp,2.5.2.v20180401-1226
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.overrides,2.5.2.v20180401-1226
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.overrides.rcp,2.5.2.v20180401-1226
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.rcp,2.5.2.v20180401-1226
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.snipmatch,2.5.2.v20180401-1226
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.snipmatch.rcp,2.5.2.v20180401-1226
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.subwords.rcp,2.5.2.v20180401-1226
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.types.rcp,2.5.2.v20180401-1226
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.utils,2.5.2.v20180401-1226
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.utils.rcp,2.5.2.v20180401-1226
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.swt,3.106.3.v20180329-0507
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64,3.106.3.v20180329-0507
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ui.genericeditor,1.0.2.v20180126-0718
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.emf,1.2.501.v201803221834
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore,1.3.0.v201803191954
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.sse.core,1.1.1002.v201711071507
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.xml.core,1.1.1101.v201711080222
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.xsd.ui,1.2.602.v201801171858
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.gradle.toolingapi,4.3.0.v20171108133209
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.jacoco.agent,0.8.1.v20180329-2024
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.jacoco.core,0.8.1.v20180329-2024
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.jacoco.report,0.8.1.v20180329-2024
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.objectweb.asm,6.0.0.v20180116-1719
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.objectweb.asm.commons,6.0.0.v20180116-1719
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.objectweb.asm.tree,6.0.0.v20180116-1719
No repository found containing: binary,epp.package.java.executable.win32.win32.x86_64,4.7.3.20180405-1200
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.buildship,2.2.1.v20180125-1441
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.e4.rcp,1.6.3.v20180329-0507
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.eclemma.feature,3.1.0.201804041601
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.egit,4.9.2.201712150930-r
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.egit.mylyn,4.9.2.201712150930-r
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.epp.logging.aeri.feature,2.0.7.v20170906-1327
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.epp.mpc,1.6.4.v20180214-1810
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.epp.package.common.feature,4.7.3.20180405-1200
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.epp.package.java.feature,4.7.3.20180405-1200
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.rcp.feature,1.3.2.v20171108-1343
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.user.ui,2.3.2.v20171108-1343
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.help,2.2.104.v20180330-0640
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.annotation,1.1.150.v20180322-1206
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.annotation,2.1.150.v20180322-1206
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jdt,3.13.4.v20180330-0919
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jgit,4.9.2.201712150930-r
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.m2e.feature,1.8.3.20180227-2137
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature,1.8.3.20180227-2137
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.editors_feature,3.0.19.201711172000
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext_feature,3.0.19.201711172000
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.platform,4.7.3.v20180330-0640
No repository found containing: binary,org.eclipse.platform.ide.executable.win32.win32.x86_64,4.7.3.M20180330-0640
No repository found containing: binary,org.eclipse.platform_root,4.7.3.v20180330-0640
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.rcp,4.7.3.v20180330-0640
No repository found containing: binary,org.eclipse.rcp_root,4.7.3.v20180330-0640
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.recommenders.mylyn.rcp.feature,2.5.2.v20180401-1226
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.recommenders.news.rcp.feature,2.5.2.v20180401-1226
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.recommenders.rcp.feature,2.5.2.v20180401-1226
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.recommenders.snipmatch.rcp.feature,2.5.2.v20180401-1226
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.statics,2.5.2.v20180401-1226
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.statics.rcp,2.5.2.v20180401-1226
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.common_core.feature,3.9.1.v201803221834
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.common_ui.feature,3.9.1.v201803221834
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.xml_core.feature,3.9.2.v201711080222
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature,3.9.2.v201803221834
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.xml_userdoc.feature,3.9.2.v201711071522`
```

I tried to fresh install eclipse but it didn't work. I removed my .eclipse, .p2 and eclipse folder from the install place and tried to install a new version of eclipse into a new directory and I got this error:

```
[2021-05-17 20:28:01] Executing bootstrap tasks
[2021-05-17 20:28:01] OpenJDK Runtime Environment 15.0.2+7-27
[2021-05-17 20:28:01] Product org.eclipse.products.epp.package.java.2021-03
[2021-05-17 20:28:01] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup 1.19.0.v20210223-0655, build=5032, branch=de1d74a6bf3addd102f8a873eabac293fbeaa3ad
[2021-05-17 20:28:01] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.core 1.19.0.v20210221-1019, build=5032, branch=de1d74a6bf3addd102f8a873eabac293fbeaa3ad
[2021-05-17 20:28:01] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2 1.16.0.v20200814-1205, build=5032, branch=de1d74a6bf3addd102f8a873eabac293fbeaa3ad
[2021-05-17 20:28:01] Performing P2 Director (Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (2021-03) + JRE 15.0.2)
[2021-05-17 20:28:01] Offline = false
[2021-05-17 20:28:01] Mirrors = true
[2021-05-17 20:28:01] Resolving 18 requirements from 4 repositoriesto C:\Users\billy\eclipse new installation\eclipse
[2021-05-17 20:28:01] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.feature.group (filter=(|(&(osgi.arch=x86_64)(osgi.os=linux))(&(osgi.arch=aarch64)(osgi.os=linux))(&(osgi.arch=x86_64)(osgi.os=macosx))(&(osgi.arch=x86_64)(osgi.os=win32))))
[2021-05-17 20:28:01] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:epp.package.java [4.19.0,5.0.0)
[2021-05-17 20:28:01] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [4.19.0,5.0.0)
[2021-05-17 20:28:01] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [4.19.0,5.0.0)
[2021-05-17 20:28:01] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.buildship.feature.group
[2021-05-17 20:28:01] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.eclemma.feature.feature.group
[2021-05-17 20:28:01] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.egit.feature.group
[2021-05-17 20:28:01] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.epp.mpc.feature.group
[2021-05-17 20:28:01] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group
[2021-05-17 20:28:01] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.jgit.feature.group
[2021-05-17 20:28:01] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group
[2021-05-17 20:28:01] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.m2e.lemminx.feature.feature.group
[2021-05-17 20:28:01] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group
[2021-05-17 20:28:01] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.editors_feature.feature.group
[2021-05-17 20:28:01] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.tips.feature.feature.group
[2021-05-17 20:28:01] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.tm.terminal.feature.feature.group
[2021-05-17 20:28:01] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.wildwebdeveloper.xml.feature.feature.group
[2021-05-17 20:28:01] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.oomph.setup.feature.group
[2021-05-17 20:28:01] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/justj/jres/15/updates/release/15.0.2
[2021-05-17 20:28:01] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/2021-03/202103121200
[2021-05-17 20:28:01] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2021-03/202103171000
[2021-05-17 20:28:01] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
[2021-05-17 20:28:01] ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf code=1002 Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest/compositeContent.xml.
java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol family: connect
  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:374)
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
  at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient45.HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.runRequest(HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.java:248)
  at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.browse.AbstractFileSystemBrowser$DirectoryJob.run(AbstractFileSystemBrowser.java:71)
  at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)

[2021-05-17 20:28:01] `
```

Please help I haven't eaten all day trying to fix this...

Comment: You can simply follow the description how to upgrade Eclipse https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F

Comment: Are you using the latest Eclipse Installer? Are you behind a proxy? You can also [direct download an IDE package as ZIP here](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/).